# Xamarin/Android - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, xamarin

I get this stacktrace in google play console (new vitals section) for many devices (Got 224 occurrences) but i really don't now how can i find the root cause of this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
```

Has anyone ever had this ? How can i find the root cause ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what the problem with your app is, but I can shed some light on why you get such an opaque stacktrace.

In mid May 2017, Google changed the way crash data was collected. Previously, the only way crash data was collected was by reporting each individual crash. After the app crashed, users would be prompted to 'Report' the crash data next time the app was opened.

Now, users can opt-in to having crash data sent automatically, without having to deliberately report each individual crash (though the old system is still in place).

For some reason, crashes reported in Xamarin Android apps under the new system are missing a large part of the stack trace that was previously available under the old model. The underlying reason is related to the way exceptions triggered from within the Zygote part of Android are specialised instances of the `java.lang.Error` and `java.lang.Exception` classes, which somehow don't inherit from `java.lang.Throwable` which is what Xamarin uses.

There's a long and detailed discussion within the Xamarin bugzilla system here, https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56653. A key paragraph reads:

> At present, it looks like Zygote and company are special-casing java.lang.Exception and java.lang.Error behavior. JavaProxyThrowable instead inherits from java.lang.Throwable -- the base class of Error and Exception -- and Zygote/etc. don't appear to support this.

Either way, the Xamarin developers have modified their systems and we just have to wait until the new version comes out.

In the meantime, you'll need to turn to other crash reporting systems like HockeyApp or Crashlytics to find out what's causing your specific problem.